# Synchronized crosshair with chartjs-plugin-crosshair in Vue application

Tags: chart.js, vuejs3

In the main component, I dynamically generate charts (they can be added and removed)

```
        <div v-for="(chart,index) in ltCharts" :key="chart" :index="index" class="flex flex-col gap-2 py-4">
            <!-- ... --!>
                <LtChart ref="charts" :date-range="dateRange" :options="chart.options"></LtChart>
            <!-- ... --!>
        </div>
```

Below is **part of the code** of the **LtChart** component

```
//chart registering part
<script setup>

import { Chart, Interaction, registerables } from 'chart.js';
import { CrosshairPlugin, Interpolate } from 'chartjs-plugin-crosshair';

Chart.register(...registerables);
Interaction.modes.interpolate = Interpolate

//....


//chart options

const chartOptions = reactive({
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    hover: {
      intersect: false
    },
    scales: {
        x: {
            type: 'time',
            min: new Date(props.options.dateStart),
            max: new Date(props.options.dateStop), 
            ticks: {
              autoSkip: true,
              maxTicksLimit: 10, 
              maxRotation: 0, 
              sampleSize: 2, 
              color: darkMode.value ? '#bababa' : '#6c757d' 
            }, 
        },
        y: {
          color: darkMode.value ? '#bababa' : '#6c757d' 
        }
    },
    plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        mode: 'interpolate',
        intersect: false
      },
      crosshair: {
        line: {
          color: '#DE6B48',  // crosshair line color
          width: 1        // crosshair line width
        },
        sync: {
          enabled: true,            // enable trace line syncing with other charts              // chart group
          suppressTooltips: false   // suppress tooltips when showing a synced tracer
        },
        zoom: {
          enabled: true,                                      // enable zooming
          zoomboxBackgroundColor: 'rgba(66,133,244,0.25)',     // background color of zoom box 
          zoomboxBorderColor: '#48F',                         // border color of zoom box
          zoomButtonText: 'Reset Zoom',                       // reset zoom button text
          zoomButtonClass: 'reset-zoom',                      // reset zoom button class
        },
        callbacks: {
          beforeZoom: () => function(start, end) {                  // called before zoom, return false to prevent zoom
            return true;
          },
          afterZoom: () => function(start, end) {                   // called after zoom
          }
        }
      }
    }

})

// creating and destroying chart
function renderChart() {
    Chart.register(CrosshairPlugin)
    const ctx = chartRef.value.getContext('2d');
    chartInstance = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: chartData,
        options: chartOptions
    })
}
function destroyChart() {
    if (chartInstance) {
        Chart.unregister(CrosshairPlugin)
        chartInstance.destroy()
        chartInstance = null;
    }
}

//....
</script>
```

What I would like to achieve is to have a synchronized crosshair for each chart. Unfortunately, each chart has its own. In the code above, I tried to include only the necessary parts.

- Plugin used: https://github.com/abelheinsbroek/chartjs-plugin-crosshair (1.2.0)
- Chart.js version: 3.9.1